# Java - ordering 3 numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a program that orders 3 numbers that I introduce and I put into an array.

The program compiles correctly, but, with numbers "6, 3, 2" I expect to get:

Initial data: 6,3,2.
Ordered data: 2, 3, 6.

But, instead of this, I get:

Initial data: 2, 3, 6.
Ordered data: 0,0,0.

Why I am getting this result?

Maybe the error could be inside the method sortData()?

Thank you!

```
import java.io.*;



public class SortNumbers {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        //Array for initial data
        int [] initialData;
        //Array for ordered data
        int [] orderedData;
        //Length of data, will be asked to the user or put it handly
        int dataLength = 3;

        initialData = inputData(dataLength); //Input data

        if (initialData!=null) { //assess data validity

            orderedData = sortData(initialData); //Sort data
            //Print results
            System.out.println("Initial data:");
            printData(initialData);
            System.out.println("Ordered data:");
            printData(orderedData);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error entering data.");
        }

    } //end main()

    /**
     * inputData()
     * Inputs an array of numbers.
     * @param int length: number of elements to input.
     * @return int []: an array containing the numbers given by the user,
     * or null in case of an error.
     */
    public static int [] inputData(int numElements) {   

        int [] data = new int [numElements];

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                //Note: you can write this in the same line
                new InputStreamReader(System.in)
            );

            for (int index=0; index<numElements; index++) {
                System.out.format("Input int number (pos %d of %d): ", index+1, numElements);
                data[index] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {     
            System.out.println("Input value must be a number!");
            data = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {   
            System.out.println("Error reading data " + e.getMessage());
            data = null;
        }

        return data;
    }

    /**
     * sortData()
     * Sorts an array of numbers
     * @param int [] inData: array of numbers to sort.
     * @return int []: an array of ordered numbers.
     */
    public static int [] sortData(int [] inData) {


        //TODO
        //outData=intData;

//http://www.java-examples.com/java-bubble-sort-example

        int [] outData = new int [inData.length];
         int temp = 0;

         for(int i=0; i < inData.length; i++){
              for(int j=1; j < (inData.length-i); j++){

                    if(inData[j-1] > inData[j]){
                        //swap the elements!
                        temp = inData[j-1];
                        inData[j-1] = inData[j];
                        inData[j] = temp;
                    }

             }
        }




        return outData;
    }

    /**
     * printData()
     * prints an array of numbers.
     * @param int [] data: data array to print.
     */
    public static void printData(int [] data) {

        for (int index=0; index<data.length; index++) {
            System.out.format("%d ", data[index]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

} //end class
```

Comment: Hint: in the method `sortData` you don't modify `outData`, so it will always be zero-filled.

Comment: In `sortData` which array you are returning, when was it filled with data and when was it sorted?

Comment: Hey @Jordi, have you seen my answer? Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Your `sortData` method sorts the array *in-place*:
the `inData` input parameter is sorted, and the `outData` parameter is never updated after it was created.
As arrays are initialized with all 0 values, you get back all 0 values.

You can make the method return `inData` instead.

Or if you don't want to modify the input array, then you can clone it to `outData`, and change all the statements that modify `inData` to use `outData` instead.

```
public static int[] sortData(int[] inData) {
    int[] outData = inData.clone();
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < outData.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (outData.length - i); j++) {
            if (outData[j - 1] > outData[j]) {
                temp = outData[j - 1];
                outData[j - 1] = outData[j];
                outData[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return outData;
}
```

Or you could let the libraries do the hard work for you, and do it better:

```
public static int[] sortData(int[] inData) {
    int[] outData = inData.clone();
    Arrays.sort(outData);
    return outData;
}
```